# Cannot find font in RMarkdown PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, xelatex, tinytex

I have dusted off an old LaTeX template that I used with RMarkdown some time ago (when it worked), updated to the latest R, RMarkdown, tinytex etc.

When I try to knit the document, it gives an error that it cannot find the Accanthis font:

> ! Package fontspec Error: The font "AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular" cannot be
> (fontspec)                found.
>
> ! name = AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular, rootname = AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular, pointsize =
>
> ! mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
> ...

This is called from the template with lines:

> \usepackage{fontspec}
>
> \setmainfont{AccanthisADFStdNo3}[
> UprightFont    = *-Regular,
> ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
> BoldFont       = *-Bold,
> BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
> Ligatures={TeX,NoRequired},
> ]

TinyTex can see the font in that
`tinytex::tlmgr_search("/AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular[.](tfm|afm|mf|otf)")`
locates an.otf file

but running from the command line
`mktextfm AccanthisADFStdNo3-Regular`
gives "mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!" and is looking for a .mf file that does not exist.

Any idea what the cause of this is?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to require a file extension after the font name, which it didn't in the past.

I changed a line in the template to include .otf

```
\setmainfont{AccanthisADFStdNo3.otf}[...
```

and it works again.