# The font "Andale Mono" cannot be found while using rstudio/bookdown package to build book

Tags: r, bookdown, tinytex, fontspec

I cloned materials of Hadley Wickham's book Advanced R Programming from a github repository https://github.com/hadley/adv-r.
I tried to build the html format book and encountered the following issues:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Andale Mono" cannot be found.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile _main.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See _main.log for more info.
Execution halted
Error: bookdown::render_book() failed to render the output format 'bookdown::pdf_book'.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Previously, I've met similar issue which said I don't have inconsolata font, I solved that issue by installing inconsolata font on my PC( Windos 10 system) and restarting R section. Therefore, I did same thing to solve this issue, I installed Andale Mono font on my PC and checked it was installed successfully. However, I still got this error message when I tried to build the book. I suspect the LaTex fail issue is also due to the font can't be found issue. Has anyone had similar issue before and know how to solve it?

Comment: Please check, if that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792423/cannot-find-font-in-rmarkdown-pdf

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm in the same spot as you. Did you find a fix?